# How to mock a middleware in supertest?

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs, supertest

I want to test if the middleware in `app.js` is called. Although I mock the module `work.js`, it still runs the original code.

app.js

```
const work = require('./work')
const express = require('require')

const app = express()
  .use(work)
  .use(...)
  .get(...)


module.exports = app
```

work.js

```
function work(req, res, next){...}

module.exports = work
```

app-test.js

```
const supertest = require('supertest')
const app = require('../app')

test('test middleware in app.js', async(done) => {
  jest.mock('../work', () => jest.fn((req, res, next) => next()))

  const agent = () => supertest(app)
  const work = require('../work')  

  await agent()
    .get('/')
    .set(...)

  expect(work).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)  // Error

  done()
})
```

I expect that `work.js` will be called once. Is there anything wrong?  Should I change my test?

Comment: According to the code you posted, the real `work` would have been appended to the middleware chain of `app` by the time the second line of `app-test.js` completed.  This may be why the real `work` is called.

Comment: @ctt I used this method to mock module ,and it could work when I did another test. However, it doesn't work when I test middleware in express. I cannot figure out what's the difference between the two tests.

Answer (score 19):

Below example works for me:

`app.js`:

```js
const work = require('./work');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.use(work).get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendStatus(200);
});

module.exports = app;
```

`work.js`:

```js
function work(req, res, next) {
  next();
}

module.exports = work;
```

`app.spec.js`:

```js
jest.mock('./work', () => jest.fn((req, res, next) => next()));

const supertest = require('supertest');
const app = require('./app');
const work = require('./work');

let agent;
let server;
beforeEach(done => {
  server = app.listen(4000, err => {
    if (err) return done(err);

    agent = supertest(server);
    done();
  });
});

afterEach(done => {
  server && server.close(done);
});

describe('app', () => {
  test('test middleware in app.js', async () => {
    const response = await agent.get('/');
    expect(response.status).toBe(200);
    expect(work).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
PASS  src/stackoverflow/56014527/app.spec.js
  app
    ✓ test middleware in app.js (90ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 app.js   |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.248s
```

Here is the completed demo: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/56014527

Comment: Is there any way to mock parameterized middleware using Sinon?
middleware definition like as:

exports.authUser = function (options) {
  return function (req, res, next) {
    // Implement the middleware function based on the options object
    next()
  }
}

Comment: @hareshhanat Please ask a new question using `sinon` tag.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have asked the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61818474/how-to-mock-configurable-middleware-in-node-js-with-sinon-and-mocha

Answer (score 2):

With a bit of tinkering I've managed to replicate slideshowp2's example (which works :)) with a version that doesn't need a server.

```
var express = require("express");
var supertest = require("supertest");
var httpContext = require("express-http-context");

var app = express();

// before uses
app.use(httpContext.middleware);
// before gets etc.
app.use(work());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  console.log("get");
  res.sendStatus(200);
});

describe("work", () => {
  it("should call work", async () => {
    var agent = supertest.agent(app);
    const res = await agent.get("/");
    expect(res.status).toBe(200);
    // expect...;
  });
  });
```

**`work.js`**

```
export function work() {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("work");
    next();
  };
}
```

Comment: This calls it, but you commented out the code that asserts the number of times it is called? `supertest.agent` still creates a server.